# Downloading Glade source

Tags: glade

I'm about to download the source code for glade from http://glade.gnome.org/sources.html
it has two options 
stable tarballs for Glade 3.8 for GTK+2
stable tarballs for Glade 3.14 for GTK+3
which one should I pick if I'm running ubuntu version  12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon whether you want to develop an application with GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3. All newer applications should be developed with GTK+ 3 because GTK+ 2 has reached its end of life. Nevertheless, there may be legitimate reasons for developing an application with GTK+ 2, such as backward compatibility with older distributions.

I'm not sure if you are aware of the fact, that both versions of Glade that you've mentioned above are already packaged for Ubuntu 12.10. You can install Glade 3.14 using the terminal with the command

```
sudo apt-get install glade
```

and Glade 3.8 with the command

```
sudo apt-get install glade-gtk2
```

There is actually no need to manually download and compile Glade, unless you want to develop Glade itself.

Comment: I'm having problems with glade, and on another question someone told me to fix it by compiling glade. Will this actually work?

Comment: Could you please describe the problem that you have with Glade? Or post the link to the question you've mentioned. Otherwise I can't tell you if your problem can be fixed by manually compiling Glade.

Comment: I was watching the 'creating your first ubuntu app' tutorial and was making a text entry box. The text entry box won't print out my url when I press enter and instantiate the widget activate. here's the code                                                 def on_urlentry_activate(self, widget):
        url = widget.get_text()

        print url()
        self.webview.open(url)                                       and here is what I get when I press enter

Comment: File "/home/leife/mybrowser1/mybrowser1/Mybrowser1Window.py", line 50, in on_urlentry_activate
    print url()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Please post a new question, I'm not sure if I can help you. There are lots of other competent people here who could help you and they won't see your problem, if you describe it in the comments.

Comment: @bender Hi. For some reasons I have to use glade3.8 because I am using gtk2 for arm based device which only suports gtk2. The command you mentioned to download glade 3.8 is not working. Can you please tell me how can I download and install glade 3.8 for gtk2